# HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse in C#

Tags: .net, web-services, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

How to use `HttpWebRequest` and `HttpWebResponse` to create a webservice and how will the request and responses will be send across the wire?

Answer (score 2):

this is the syntax for using HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse

```
WebRequest _request;
string text;
string url = "UrlToGet";
_request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
using (WebResponse response = _request.GetResponse())
{
    using (StreamReader reader =new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
         text = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

Comment: It is really a good idea to specify an encoding in the constructor `new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8)`.

Answer (score 1):

`HttpWebRequest` and `HttpWebResponse` are intended for client applications to make HTTP requests and read HTTP responses. You can't use them to create a server application.

If you want to create and consume SOAP web services using .NET then you need to learn WCF:

> [Windows Communication Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456779.aspx)

WCF is a complex topic but Microsoft still support the legacy "ASP.NET Web Services" technology which might be easier to get a handle on to begin with:

> [ASP.NET Web Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t745kdsh.aspx)

In particular:

> [XML Web Services Using ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba0z6a33.aspx)

Comment: Can you suggest a way to communicate a server and client using basic soap messages

Comment: Do you mean how to create both the server and the client?

Comment: Ok if it is only the webservice that read a soap message and send back the response after fetching data from the database please help me

Comment: Do you have any link or sample for implementing the above using WCF

Comment: http://carvingcode.blogspot.com/2010/04/creating-wcf-web-service-with-vs2010.html