# System.Net.HttpWebRequest Response

Tags: c#, asp.net

Need some help figuring something out. First time doing this and everything I have read does not seem to help. I am trying to get a response from an api call and get back the results in my label but all I get is **System.Net.HttpWebRequest** in my label, so its sending and coming back at least. 
Is there something else I need to do to get back the expected response?

```
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
    WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(@"https://server.net/api/v1/.." + Id_TextBox.Text);
    req.Method = "POST";
    req.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes("Login:######"));
    HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();//(HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
    myString_Label.Text = req.ToString();
```

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6723792/httpwebrequest-and-httpwebresponse-in-c-sharp)

Comment: By calling ToString() on the request object, you're getting the object's string representation. You would want to either call ToString() on resp, or deserialize the response into an object you can then display.

Comment: Take a look at the sample: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to do as below , you can also get same from MSDN

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.getresponsestream(v=vs.110).aspx

```
HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
Stream receiveStream = resp.GetResponseStream();
Encoding encode = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
// Pipes the stream to a higher level stream reader with the required encoding format. 
StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader( receiveStream, encode );
Console.WriteLine("\r\nResponse stream received.");

Char[] read = new Char[256];
            // Reads 256 characters at a time.    
int count = readStream.Read( read, 0, 256 );
Console.WriteLine("HTML...\r\n");
while (count > 0) 
    {
                    // Dumps the 256 characters on a string and displays the string to the console.
        String str = new String(read, 0, count);
        Console.Write(str);
        count = readStream.Read(read, 0, 256);
    }
Console.WriteLine("");
// Releases the resources of the response.
myHttpWebResponse.Close();
// Releases the resources of the Stream.
readStream.Close();
```

Comment: Ok, sorry I was in a meeting. I will try to incorporate this.